# Position page content inbetween two sidebars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position vertical Google Adsense banners to the left and right of my webpage's content, but I'm not sure how.  Ultimately I'd like it to look like this picture:

[image: Template showing ads on each side of content]

Comment: Please share the HTML/CSS you have so far, it will help people point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Make three seperate `div` 's :

- One for the left banner
- One for the main content of the page
- One for the right banner

HTML :

```
 <div class="sidebar"></div>
 <div id="content"></div>
 <div class="sidebar"></div>
```

Then, position them with CSS.

```
.sidebar{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10%;
}   

#content{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Note that if you do this, you have to get rid of the [inline-block space](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

You can use `box-sizing: border-box` on your `div` 's if you want to prevent the borders and paddings from messing with your width's, and pushing down the right sidebar.